# Assigning products to categories, advanced search operators / regex?

Tags: catalog, category, grid, products-management, products

In Magento I'm trying to find a fast way to assign products to categories from the `Manage Categories` section. After I select a category and click on `Category Products` I'm wondering if there's a way to make the `Name` field searchable through Regex or at least to use a wildcard.

Example: entering `nike * shoes` in the name field would return results for `nike running shoes` and `nike shoes`

Screenshot: http://goo.gl/DM0s2g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you will have to change the way that the grid does it's filtering. If you look into the file `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` you will see the function `_addColumnFilterToCollection` here is where all the action happens when adding filters. But good news there appears to already be a function that allows for a custom filter callback `if ($column->getFilterConditionCallback()) {`.

Good work Magento! Sometimes there is just the piece of code you need ready and waiting to be used, you just need to know about it.

So how do we use this, well let's simply find an example that Magento already has and copy how it works ;)

After a quick search for `filter_condition_callback` we end up in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Page_Grid`. You can see that this filter callback is used on the column `store_id` as part of the `addColumn` call:

```
'filter_condition_callback'
                => array($this, '_filterStoreCondition'),
```

Nice so then in that block there is a function `_filterStoreCondition` which contains the custom filter code.

```
protected function _filterStoreCondition($collection, $column)
{
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return;
    }

    $this->getCollection()->addStoreFilter($value);
}
```

So it seems that can be very powerful, since we have the value, withh all other filter information, and then we also have the collection that we want to manipulate.

All it does is get the value of the column and then adds a custom filter to the collection. So it would be fairly simple to create your own filter that uses something like:

```
$this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('name', array('regexp' => $value))
```

Hope this helps point you in the right direction.